# What are the simple Heesch-2 polyforms?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, tiling

[image: Almost3]

At the [Tiling Database](http://www.polyomino.org.uk/mathematics/polyform-tiling/):

There are 3, 20, 198, 1390 non-tiling polyominoes of order 7 to 10.
There are 4, 37, 381, 2717 non-tiling polyhexes of order 6 to 9.
There are 1, 0, 20, 103, 594, 1192, 6290 non-tiling polyiamonds of order 7 to 13.

Have these non-tilers had their [Heesch numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heesch's_problem) determined?  A non-tiler that can surround itself is Heesch-1.  If a second complete ring can be made, that's Heesch-2.

What simple polyforms are Heesch-2?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heesch numbers of some polyominoes and polyiamonds (but not polyhexes) were determined here: http://isohedral.ca/heesch-numbers-part-2-polyforms/

Minimal Heesch 2 polyomino has 9 (not 11 as on your picture) squares:

[image: the only 9-mino with Heesch number 2]

Minimal polyamond with Heesch number 3 has 10 triangles:

[image: 10-iamond with Heesch number 3]

Heesch numbers of edge-marked polyforms (including polyhexes) were studied here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10586458.2015.1096867

Since this article is not available for free, here are 2 examples from it:

5-hex with marked edges and Heesch number 3:

[image: 5-hex with marked edges and Heesch number 3]

13-iamond with marked edges and Heesch number 4:

[image: 13-iamond with marked edges and Heesch number 4]

Answer (score 2):

Glenn Rhoads found the minimal Heesch 2 polyomino in his 2003 thesis "Planar Tilings and the Search for an Aperiodic Prototile".

[image]